# How to immediately access a component of an anonymous structure created with CONV?

Tags: abap

The below code gives a syntax error.

```
DATA: lt_vbeln TYPE TABLE OF vbeln.
SELECT * FROM EDID4 INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_edid4).
lt_vbeln = value #( for ls_edid4 in lt_edid4 ( conv E1NTHDR( ls_edid4-sdata )-vbeln ).
```

Table `EDID4` contains field `SDATA` of type `LCHR` (`char`, length 1000).
I want to convert it into structure `E1NTHDR` and immediately read its `VBELN` property.

How to do this inline ?

EDIT: The system has SAP_ABA 75G SP 0003.

Comment: I have fixed a typo, replacing `lt_result` with `lt_vbeln`. Which ABAP version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this code in all versions since ABAP 7.40 SP 5, by defining an auxiliary variable with [`LET ... IN`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abaplet.htm):

```
DATA: lt_vbeln TYPE TABLE OF vbeln.
SELECT * FROM edid4 INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_edid4).
lt_vbeln = VALUE #( FOR ls_edid4 IN lt_edid4
                    WHERE ( segnam = 'E1NTHDR' )
                    LET aux_e1nthdr = CONV e1nthdr( ls_edid4-sdata )
                    IN
                    ( aux_e1nthdr-vbeln ) ).
```

EDIT: <strike>There are new ways of accessing components dynamically in more recent ABAP versions.</strike>

In the latest ABAP version, 7.58, there is no better way. Reference in the ABAP documentation:

- [Constructor Operators for Constructor Expressions](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_758_index_htm/7.58/en-US/index.htm?file=abenconstructor_expressions.htm): ***« Unlike method chainings or table expressions, constructor expressions cannot be placed on the left side of a structure component selector, since constructing a structure only to access a single component is pointless. »***

  - i.e. the [structure component selector](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_758_index_htm/7.58/en-US/index.htm?file=abenstructure_component_sel_glosry.htm) being `-` (e.g. in `struct-comp`), it's not possible to use something like `CONV e1nthdr( xx )-component`.
  - It wouldn't be so pointless for [`CONV`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_758_index_htm/7.58/en-US/index.htm?file=abenconstructor_expression_conv.htm), but the documentation doesn't add any precision.
- Extra information in the same chapter about Constructor Operators:

  - What is possible after a constructor operator, seems limited to `NEW` and `CAST` (nothing allowed for other constructor operators): *« Expressions with the operators NEW and CAST can be positioned directly in front of the object component selector -> and can occur in chainings. »*
  - Remark about `LET`: *« LET expressions can be used to define local helper fields in all suitable constructor expressions. »*

Comment: Thanks. What are the newer ways ? The system has SAP_ABA 75G SP 0003.

Comment: As far as I know, SAP_ABA 75G = ABAP 7.57. I was thinking of the expressions presented in this first [blog post](https://blogs.sap.com/2021/10/19/new-kinds-of-abap-expressions/) and its sequel, but I'm not so sure. I will check if there's really a better alternative.

Comment: I have read the ABAP documentation 7.58, there's no better way.

Comment: EDIT: SAP_ABA 75G = ABAP 7.56 (75A means ABAP 7.50). SAP_ABA 75G is probably delivered with **SAP_BASIS 756** which better indicates the ABAP version.